# input() call where text is typed at custom position in the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

This is actually a question I've had since I first started learning Python a year ago. And it is the following: *How can I call the  `input` function and have the users type their entry at some point other than the end of the `prompt`?*

To clarify, say I had the string

```
'Enter file size: MB'
```

And when called I would want the text to be inserted like so:

```
Enter file size: 62 MB
```

Is it possible to recreate this behavior in a function call like the following?

```
input('Enter file size: {} MB')
# where Python would interpret
# the {} as the position to input text
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, though I would just write `Enter file size in MB:` and focus on other tasks

Comment: Is a Linux / Unix answer ok? Or does it also need to work on Windows?

Comment: @soon That example was just, well, an example. I just thought it was an interesting idea to post this as a not-necessarily-very-applicable question

Comment: @PM2Ring Windows support would be preferable, but any ideas are appreciated regardless.

Comment: Such functionality needs the `curses` module (part of Python standard library for Unix-based systems) or similar

Comment: @PM2Ring This is StackOverflow! Of course it's ok. The OP's OS is hardly relevant. I'm sure plenty of linux users will find this question on <insert search engine of choice>.

Answer (score 3):

This works on both Windows and Linux:

```
import sys
print("                    MB\rEnter file size: ", end = "")
file_size = sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]
```

On Linux (**not** Windows), you can also use `input("                    MB\rEnter file size: ")`.

Here's a function that makes it a little easier to use:

```
import sys

def input_multipart(prefix, gap_length, suffix):
    print(" " * (len(prefix) + gap_length) + suffix + "\r" + prefix, end = "")
    return sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]
```

Usage:

```
file_size = input_multipart("Enter file size: ", 3, "MB")
```

Output:

```
Enter file size:    MB
```

Comment: @SruthiV This sort of thing tends to depend on the terminal & OS. It's not hard to do it on a standard OS, but it gets tricky if you want it to be portable to non-standard quirky proprietary systems. ;)

Comment: @SruthiV That was just an example of what I was demonstrating. Any answers will do just fine! I could easily extend the functionality shown here to accomplish what I had thought of originally

Answer (score 2):

(Linux)

**EDIT :** One way to do it is :

```
file_size=input("Enter file size :       MB\rEnter file size : ")
```

You can also try :

```
file_size=input("Enter file size:     MB \x1B[6D")
#Enter file size:  12 MB
```

In `\x1B[6D` the 6 here moves the cursor six places backwards and lets the user enter the value after the `:` but before the `MB`

[image]
[image]

Comment: @roganjosh Did you try it out, it works for me. It is in the right hand side. It gives 'Enter file size: MB' and lets me type out 12 after the `:` and before the `MB` hence becoming 'Enter file size: 12  MB'

Comment: The disadvantage of this answer is that if the user backspaces over their input, it deletes the "MB" as well.

Comment: We might have an issue with OSs here. I'm testing on Windows.

Comment: @roganjosh My tests show that it works on Linux but not Windows.

Comment: @anonymoose yes you are right about the disadvantage

Comment: @roganjosh Does this work on Windows : `file_size=input("Enter file size :       MB\rEnter file size : ")`

Comment: @SruthiV nope :/

Comment: It's *possible* to make this code work on Windows, but you will need to enable support of ANSI control sequences. That's do-able in any terminal, but probably easiest in PowerShell. Ask someone who knows low-level Windows stuff for details of how to do that. ;)